# More RSS items in the same Message using Telegram

Tags: html, xml, rss, telegram-bot

I'm making a newsletter for Telegram using a bot to send to all my subscribers some news that I post everyday.

But, I want them to receive all this news at a specific hour, for example, every day they will receive all the news of the day at 8 pm.

My question is, can I put all the feeds of the news in the same message? 
For example, if I post 3 new posts, at 8 PM I want that my subscribers receive 1 message which contains the 3 posts that I posted.

Answer (score 0):

You Can use a Wordpress Plugin ( AutoPublish Posts Telegram Channels) and Connect WP to Bot and Set Cronjob on WP that run every day 8:00 AM , 
When Cronjob Run all published posts on 24 hours Sent to Bots user on One messeges.